# Sequalize spawning unnecessary connection to write instance

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

I have the following Sequalize connection config, I also have a read replica setup. Based on the docs all raw 'SELECT' queries when specified correctly should be delegated to the specific read replica. For some reason when a query executes, a connection is spawned for the main write instance first as if it would completely ignore the use of `useMaster: false` in the query execution. The connection to the main instance then closes almost instantly and the connection is made to the read replica to execute the query.

Why that is? How could I ignore making a connection to the write instance all the time, feel like there is no real advantage of a read replica in this case as I am always limited by the size of the write instance if every query requires a connection to it.

The Sequalize connection function:

```js
export const connectToSqlDatabase = async (
    config: SqlDatabaseConfig,
): Promise<SqlDatabaseConnectResult> => {
    const name = config.name;
    const { readReplicas, ...connectionConfig } = config.connect;

    const sequelizeOptions: Options  = {
        ...connectionConfig,
        logging: false,
        pool: {
            max: 1,
            min: 0,
            acquire: 30000,
            idle: 10000,
        },
    };

    if (readReplicas && readReplicas.length > 0) {
        sequelizeOptions.replication = {
            read: readReplicas,
            write: { host: connectionConfig.host },
        };
    }

    const db: SqlDatabaseConnectResult = Object.assign(
        new Sequelize(sequelizeOptions),
        { fresh: true },
    );
    
    try {
        db.lastAuthenticated = Date.now();
        await db.authenticate();    
        db.name = name;
        
        return (connectedDatabases[name] = db);
    } catch (error) {
        
        throw error;
    }
};
```

And this is how I filter query types in another function:

I've tested and in a case of a SELECT query it always enters the right condition and executes the `useMaster:false` query

```js
export const executeSqlQuery = async <T, R = any>(
    db: SqlDatabase,
    query: string,
): Promise<[R[]]> => {
    try{
        if (query.includes("SELECT")) {
            return [(await db.query(query, { type: QueryTypes.SELECT, useMaster: false, raw: true })) as any];
        }
        return (await db.query(convertedQuery, { useMaster: true })) as any;

// ... Rest of the code
```